# In UWP, how can I scale an item on GridView when item is selected?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm using UWP to build an XBOX ONE app. I have a GridView and I need to scale the width and height of the selected Item. Anyone has an example of how to perform that behavior?

Comment: You can add a Storyboard to do it in the VisualStateManager of the Style Template to do it on IsSelected state.

Answer (score 1):

> In UWP, how can I scale an item on GridView when item is selected?

Firstly, for how to scale an item you can use [ScaleTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.scaletransform) class. You can scales an object in the two-dimensional x-y coordinate system. To meet your requirements here you can create a `ScaleTranform` object for the `ContentBorder` of the `GridView` item's style template.

```
 <Grid
     x:Name="ContentBorder"
     Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
     BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
     BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
     <Grid.RenderTransform>
         <ScaleTransform x:Name="contentborderscale"></ScaleTransform>
     </Grid.RenderTransform>
```

Secondly, for how to change the visual state when item is selected, you need to change the `PointerOverSelected` state or `Selected` state based on the default [GridViewItem styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299127.aspx). You can add the following animations to the `PointOverSelected` visual state to implement the scale.

```
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="contentborderscale" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" >
     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1.5" />
 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="contentborderscale" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX">
     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1.5" />
 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

I wrote a completed demo about when the `GridView` item selected, the `height` and `width` of the item will scale to 150%. You can download the demo [here](https://github.com/sunteenwu/CGridViewScale).

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do it using Visual States, I'm now facing another issue, when I scale the gridview item (in my case is a picture) it overlaps with other gridview items, I want the selected item to be on top of every item in the gridview, by setting the ZIndex somehow, I still haven't figured out, any ideas?

Comment: @chavakane. Sorry for the later response. Have you resolved your new issue? Did you still need help?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT I am having a similar problem with the items (only some) overlapping ..can you look at it ? Not sure where I am going wrong here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130969/irregular-behavior-xaml-uwp-community-toolkit-scale-animation