# Enable effects on mouse hover in UWP GridView items

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I want to have some simple effects such as scale or dim/fade the gridview item when hovering the mouse over an item in GridView. How can I achieve this. Some examples of what I want to achieve is as below.

Example 1 (Scale):

```
`https://codepen.io/wifeo/pen/qzwkb`
```

Example 2 (Fade):

```
`http://codepen.io/chrisgrabinski/full/gpqtc/`
```

Comment: Hi, you're going to need to customize the XAML in the Style Template of GridView/GridViewItem which you can find some basic examples of with a quick google search for something like 'Customizing GridView XAML' and after you've tried some things when you've got some code to show with a more specific question come on back and would be happy to help. However some effort shown is usually required first. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, I am certain that this has nothing to do with styling the template of the GridViewItem. I am looking for something like a behavior which on mover hover, starts some animation to scale of fade or highlight the gridviewitem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Example 1 (Scale) -- when hovering the mouse over an item in GridView

The first question should have been answered on SO:[In UWP, how can I scale an item on GridView when item is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39795718/in-uwp-how-can-i-scale-an-item-on-gridview-when-item-is-selected) According to your requirement, you just need to use PointerEntered and PointerExited event to get it.

> Example 2 (Fade)

The second question, you need to know [Fade animation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br210298) I've made a simple code sample for your reference.

```
<GridView x:Name="gv">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid PointerEntered="Grid_PointerEntered" PointerExited="Grid_PointerExited">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Name="EnterStoryboard">
                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myRectangle" />
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Name="ExitStoryboard">
                            <FadeInThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myRectangle" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" x:Name="myRectangle" Width="100" Height="100"></Rectangle>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

```cs
private void Grid_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard sb = ((Grid)sender).Resources["EnterStoryboard"] as Storyboard;
        sb.Begin();
    }

    private void Grid_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard sb = ((Grid)sender).Resources["ExitStoryboard"] as Storyboard;
        sb.Begin();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems like a logical solution. Will try and let you know the results.