# How to scale content of Gridviewitem in uwp

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

How to scale content of Grid View item to fit a complete grid cell without increasing size of Gridviewitem (without overlay with other items).

Comment: You can refer to this question .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130969/irregular-behavior-xaml-uwp-community-toolkit-scale-animation

Comment: Thanks. It works for me.